# How can I mount the Hololens 2 filesystem via WiFi to access its files?

Tags: linux, mount, hololens

I have some files I need to extract from the Hololens 2. I can individually download them from the Developer Portal, but I would like to be able to access the internal storage using Linux so that I can run e.g. `sha256sum` to compare files that I've extracted.

This is currently possible if I connect the HoloLens to the PC with a USB cable, as Ubuntu mounts the storage using `gvfs`. But I would like to do so without a cable, since I may not always have one on hand.

Please let me know if there have been solutions to export Hololens storage as NFS or Samba shares.